# How can I stop a React component from rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

I'm using React Native and I'm trying to make the DownBar component don't show when I logout from my app. The main Component **does** show, but my Downbar component won't gone, it woult still be showing.

I've tried multiple solutions , asked chat gpt and searched for info but I'm stuck.

Approach 1:

HandlingLogout:

```
const [logoutSuccessful, setLogoutSuccessful ] = useState(false);
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const handleLogout = () => {
signOut(auth).then(() => {
    console.log("Logout successful.")
    setLogoutSuccessful(true);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("-----------ERROR----------")
    console.error(error);
});
}
if(logoutSuccessful){
return(
<>
<PruebaDownbar isLoggedIn={false}/>
</>
)
}
```

Approach 1:

The Main Component:
export default function Main() {
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>


)
}

This is my DownBar Component. I tried wrapping it with {isLoggedIn && (....)} as I show below but it won't work neither:

```
export default function DownBar( {isLoggedIn}) {

{!isLoggedIn && (<AuthMenu/>)}

{isLoggedIn && (
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }}
  tabBar={({ navigation, state, descriptors, insets }) => (
    <BottomNavigation.Bar
      navigationState={state}
     safeAreaInsets={insets}
     inactiveColor='white'
     activeColor='#F29C46'
     style={{backgroundColor:'#303747'}}
      onTabPress={({ route, preventDefault }) => {
        const event = navigation.emit({
          type: 'tabPress',
          target: route.key,
          canPreventDefault: true,
        });
/>
)
}
```

Approach 2 (and the first one I tried):  simply calling  that calls  when logging out.

HandlingLogout:

```
const handleLogout = () => {
     same as approach1
}


if(logoutSuccessful){
return(
<Main/>
)
}
```

Main Component:

```
export default function Main() {
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AuthMenu/>
    </View>
)
```

}

DownBar Component:

```
export default function MyComponent( ) {

return(

<Tab.Navigator
screenOptions={{
headerShown: false,
}}
tabBar={({ navigation, state, descriptors, insets }) => (
<BottomNavigation.Bar

/>
)
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your DownBar component is missing a return, it wouldn't render at all the way it's written in the question, but that's the opposite problem.